# Blowfish encrypted string becomes gibberish

Tags: ruby, api, encryption, blowfish

I need to communicate with an API that requires the request to be encoded in Blowfish and Base64.

In my custom library I start off with:

```
# encoding: utf-8
require "base64"
require 'crypt/blowfish'
```

I create an instance:

```
@blowfish_key = '1234567887654321'
@blowfish     = Crypt::Blowfish.new(@blowfish_key)
```

And further down I create the encrypted string (or 'ticket' as the API calls it)

```
@string_to_encrypt  = "#{@partnerid},#{user.id},#{exam_id},#{return_url},#{time_stamp}"
@enc                = @blowfish.encrypt_string(@string_to_encrypt)
```

In the Rails console I can decrypt with `@blowfish.decrypt_string(@enc)` without any problems. But the API gives me gibberish:

```
Invalid ticket:
Decrypted String  :)IŠkó}*Ogû…xÃË-ÖÐHé%q‹×ÎmªÇjEê !©†xRðá=Í²    [À}=»ïN)'sïƒJJ=:›õ)¦$ô1X¢
```

Also, when I encrypt something simple in the console, like "Hello", and feed the encrypted string to an online Blowfish decoder, like http://webnet77.com/cgi-bin/helpers/blowfish.pl, I get the same gibberish mess back.

It's like the Ruby blowfish encryption is a format that is not used anywhere else.

**Note:**

In my actual application I send the encrypted string via a  form field to the Webservice. The encrypted string is Base64 encoded and prefixed with an 'a'.

```
@enc = Base64.encode64(@enc)
@enc = 'a' + CGI::escape(@enc)
```

This is explained in their documentation:

**Format of the ticket:**

```
t=’a’ + URL_Encode (
Base64_Encode (
Blowfish_Encrypt ( ‘partnerid,user_id,test_id,URL_Encode(return_URL),ticket_timestamp’, ‘blowfish_key’)
      )
)
```

> Note above that the Blowfish_Encrypt function accepts two parameters-
>   1)the string to encrypt and 2)a hex key. Also note that the ticket has
>   been prefixed with a lower case ‘a’ (ASCII 97).

**Example of what the HTML form will look like:**

```
<form method=”POST” action=”http://www.expertrating.com/partner_site_name/”>
<input type=”hidden” name=”t” value=”adfinoidfhdfnsdfnoihoweirhqwdnd2394yuhealsnkxc234rwef45324fvsdf2” />
<input type=”submit” name=”submit” value=”Proceed to take the Test” />
</form>
```

I am lost, where do I go wrong?

Comment: You do realize that encrypted data is essentially binary barbage? It only becomes "readable" if you do something like base-64 encoding on it.

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of things:

1) As was said in the comments, if you print the encrypted strings, then this is almost always causing trouble because the encrypted strings are very likely to contain non-ASCII characters that will either be unprintable or in a representation that is not understood by others. The best way to achieve a representation that is widely understood is to encode the result using Base64 or Hex encoding, so the Base64 encoding you apply in your application is fine for that.

2) The Perl app you linked to uses for example hex encoding. As a consequence, it will also only accept encrypted strings in hex encoding. That's why it wouldn't accept any of your inputs at all. You get hex encoding suitable for the application as follows:

```
hex = encrypted.unpack("H*")[0].upcase
```

3) But still no luck with the Perl app. One reason is this (taken from Crypt sources):

```
def encrypt_stream(plainStream, cryptStream)
  initVector = generate_initialization_vector(block_size() / 4)
  chain = encrypt_block(initVector)
  cryptStream.write(chain)
```

What this means is that Crypt writes the IV as the first block of the encrypted message. This is totally fine, but most modern crypto libraries I know won't prepend the IV but rather assume it is exchanged as out-of-band information between the two communicating parties.

4) But even knowing this, you will still have no luck with the Perl app. The reason is that the Perl app uses ECB mode encryption where the Crypt gem uses CBC mode. CBC mode uses an IV, so even one-block messages won't match except if you are using an all-zero IV. But using an all-zero IV (or any other deterministic IV) is [bad practice](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/Cipher.html) (and Crypt doesn't do it anyway). Doing so allows distinguishing the first block from random and opens you up to attacks like [BEAST](http://www.educatedguesswork.org/2011/09/security_impact_of_the_rizzodu.html). Using ECB is bad practice as well except for totally rare edge cases. So let's forget about that Perl app and concentrate on the things at hand.

5) I'm naturally in favor of using Ruby OpenSSL, but in this case I think I'm not being subjective if I tell you it's better for overall security to use it instead of the Crypt gem. Just telling you so would be lame, so here's two reasons why:

- Crypt generates its IVs using a predictable random generator (a combination of `srand` and `rand`), but that's not good enough. It has to be a cryptographically secure random generator.
- Crypt seems to be no longer maintained and there have been some things going on in the meantime that either were unknown at the time or that were never in the scope of that project. For example, OpenSSL starts to deal with leakage-resilient cryptography to prevent side-channel attacks that target timing, cache misses etc. That has probably never been the intention of Crypt, but such attacks pose a real threat in real life.

6) If my preaching has convinced you to make the change, then I could continue and ask you whether it really has to be Blowfish. The algorithm itself is outstanding, no doubt, but there are better, even more secure options available now, such as AES for example. If it absolutely has to be Blowfish, it's supported by Ruby OpenSSL as well:

```
cipher = OpenSSL::Cipher.new('bf-cbc')
```

7) If your production key looks like the one in the example, then there's another weak spot. There's not enough entropy in such strings. What you should do is again use a cryptographically secure random generator to generate your key, which is quite easy in Ruby OpenSSL:

```
key = cipher.random_key
```

The nice thing is it will automatically choose an appropriate key length depending on the cipher algorithm to be used.

8) Finally, am I right in assuming that you use that encrypted result as some form of authentication token? As in you append it to the HTML being rendered, wait to receive it back in some POST request and compare the received token with the original in order to authenticate some action? If this is the case, then this would again be bad practice. This time even more so. You are not using authenticated encryption here, which means that your ciphertext is *malleable*. This implies that an attacker can relatively easily forge the contents of that token without actually knowing your encryption key. This leads to all sorts of attacks, even leading to total compromise involving key recovery.

You **must** either use authenticated encryption modes (GCM, CCM, EAX...) or use a message authentication code to detect if the ciphertexts had been tampered with. Even better, don't use encryption at all and generate your tickets by using a secure hash function. The key here is to compute the hash of a securely randomized value, otherwise it is again possible to predict the outcome. A timestamp, as used in your example, is not enough. It has to be a cryptographically secure nonce, probably generated by [SecureRandom](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/securerandom/rdoc/SecureRandom.html).

But then you still have to consider replay of such tokens, token hijacking, ... you see, it's not that easy.

Comment: Wow, that is some answer. Thank you for that. As you may have guessed, I don't have the experience you obviously have using encryption methods. So I appreciate the help. The ticket has to be Blowfish and Base64. I send the ticket as a hidden form field to an online test-taking service, the Webservice decrypts it which gives them the necessary information to allow the user to take an online test. After the test, the user gets redirected back to my website - the return URL, user ID, test ID, etc. are found in the encrypted ticket.

Comment: The thing is -- they tell you its ABSOLUTELY mandatory to use Blowfish and to create the ticket according to their specifications. They also give you a Blowfish key to use, so I don't get to choose a key myself. You can actually test the encryption via their site -- http://dev.expertrating.com/blowfish/BlowfishDemo.asp

Comment: Hehe, yeah, I know the situation. So OK, you have to use what they give you, I wasn't sure if you had influence on the algorithms... Ok, then let that be their problem :) I'd still recommend using OpenSSL because Crypt also uses a less common padding scheme that they probably don't understand. Is there a spec for the exact parameters they use?

Comment: If you look at my original post, you see a section called "Format of the ticket". How would I use OpenSSL to encode the Blowfish part of that? And can I use Base64.encode64 as usual?

Comment: No, I meant the cipher parameters, key length, mode, padding scheme etc.? Judging from their demo page I'd say it has to be hex encoding. To use Ruby OpenSSL, have a look at the [Cipher docs](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/openssl/rdoc/OpenSSL/Cipher.html).